# Error using rails command on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am starting to learn about ruby on rails but somehow I got an issue calling `rails` in my project folder. When I call `rails --version` on a non project generated by rails it worked fine, but when I call inside the project, I get this error

```
❯ rails -v
/Users/mac/Devs/Rails/test/rails-test-api/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/mac/Devs/Rails/test/rails-test-api/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Any rails command won't work inside my project folder.

I am running on Macbook Pro M1 Monterey 12.6 and already open my terminal in Rosetta. This is my spec

```
❯ rails -v
Rails 7.0.4

~
❯ ruby --version
ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [x86_64-darwin21]

~
❯ rails --version
Rails 7.0.4

~
❯ bundle version
Bundler version 2.3.23 (2022-10-05 commit 250d9d485d)

~
❯ gem --version
3.3.7
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**--Edited**

- I already add `gem "bootsnap", require: false` in my `Gemfile`, then I installed it but still get those error.

```
❯ rails --version
/Users/mac/Devs/Rails/test/rails-test-api/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/mac/Devs/Rails/test/rails-test-api/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

- I also already remove the bootsnap from my `Gemfile` and commented `require "bootsnap/setup"` in my `boot.rb`. But it leads to another error

```
❯ rails --version
bin/rails:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- rails/commands (LoadError)
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

**--Edited**
I added `gem 'bootsnap'` into my Gemfile, run `bundle install`, I got `Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 41 gems now installed.` but I see no bootsnap installation there.

I already install bootsnap manually `gem install bootsnap`, succeed. But if i tried to `bundle info bootsnap` it will return `Could not find gem 'bootsnap'.`

Comment: have you tried `bundle exec rails -v`?

Comment: I get this error `can't find executable rails for gem railties. railties is not currently included in the bundle, perhaps you meant to add it to your Gemfile?` when running that

Comment: Probably you haven't rails in the `Gemfile`. How it looks?

Answer (score 1):

The error says `cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)`, which means you are having issue with the `gem bootsnap`, which main job is to run rails startup time.

If you want `bootsnap`,  add `gem bootsnap` to your gemfile.

If you don't want it, remove the line require 'bootsnap/setup' in `config/boot.rb`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. But I already did what you've told, I added some step I have tried before.

Comment: Can you try the following:

1. `bundle update bootsnap`
2. If first didnt work, try:
   - go to the project home, then cd into tmp/cache
   - delete `bootsnap-load-path-cache` and `bootsnap-compile-cache`

Comment: running `bundle update bootsnap` returned `Could not find gem 'bootsnap'.` but I already add `gem 'bootsnap'` in my gemfile. I tried to brows `tmp/cache` but it was empty.

Comment: Can you also install with `gem install bootsnap` command in your terminal and see if that fix the issue.

Comment: already did those step, `Successfully installed bootsnap-1.13.0` but error still appears. somehow, all of gem that listed on gemfile will not installed.

Comment: what you get when you do `bundle install` in the project directory?

Comment: It was `Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 41 gems now installed.` but i see no `bootsnap` on the list, is it expected?

Comment: Yes, you do need `bootsnap`. It was already reported, Try solutions mention here: https://github.com/Shopify/bootsnap/issues/73

Comment: I already gave a comment in that thread few days before I posted a question here. But still no solution yet. I think I am gonna do development with docker container

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is pretty much a configuration problem. Bundler installation folder was not located properly.
First, add `bootsnap` in the Gemfile.
Try `bundle install --path vendor/bundle` to assign a installation location and then `bundle exec rails -v`

If this doesn't work, try to reinstall the bundler

Answer (score 1):

Hope you're doing well - could you please give us more info? is it the same setup as this one? [rails-api-playground](https://github.com/riyanpratamap/rails-api-playground) (got this from your github repos), what's the output of the following commands?

`which ruby`

`gem info bundler`

`bundle install`

would be helpful if we can take a look at your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` as well. I believe it is a configuration issue as @kevin mentioned in the other answer.

will do my best to try and help you.